# Android: Connecting to External Database

Tags: java, android, database

I recently decided to follow an old dream of mine: to create an online text-based RPG. Apart from illustrations and icons it won't have any graphics. It will be played through menus and multiple choice options.
I have a few years of PHP and mySQL experience from a browser game but none in the java and android fronts. That's one of the reasons i picked android for the game... to learn new stuff in the process.

On to my question: What's the most effective (in terms of performance and security) way to connect an android app to a database hosted in an external server? I've been looking at this the last few days and so far i'm leaning towards connecting it by building a web service in PHP and then returning the results in JSON but i heard it's a slow method.
Is this approach possible with very heavy database usage without causing a lot of lag? Almost every player action will require storing or getting something from the Database.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you will need to implement an API of some kind. You don't want to allow your apps to connect directly to a remote database and run queries.